# iPhone Device Pictures

Tags: iphone, ipad, device, image, angle

Wondering if anybody knows where I can find any high resolution pictures for iPhone, iPad, iPod devices, such as:

http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/about/2010/10/about_mobile.jpg
http://www.bottlerocketapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/ipadlarge.jpg
http://images.apple.com/ipad/business/images/hero_20110302.jpg

Cheers.

Comment: This link seems up to date as of now: http://www.apple.com/pr/products/
However these might not be suitable for some occasions because they have a lighting filter used on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone:
http://www.apple.com/iphone/gallery/

Apple.com is a really great place to get stock images of apple products.

Comment: This link is outdated. Anything else?

Comment: http://www.apple.com/pr/products/iphone/iphone.html has some for the iPhone. http://www.apple.com/pr/products/ipad/ipad.html has some for the iPad.